# Why is there an Error with modbus using TCP Matlab?

Tags: matlab, remote-access, modbus, modbus-tcp

I'm working on a matlab project to remotely control a machine using the Modbus TCP protocol. The server is in "Listening" and the ports are open but when I try to read an address it doesn't work. Error of the type "a communication error occurred while reading from the modbus server: timeout occurred will know for a response." does anyone know where the problem could come from?

I try to read and write data on the machine using the modbus protocol.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As per the above more info will be needed. For example have you confirmed that the "machine" responds to the same request made in another way (e.g. [mbpoll](https://github.com/epsilonrt/mbpoll)/[modpoll](https://www.modbusdriver.com/modpoll.html)/[QModMaster](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qmodmaster/)). If that works then share info on the test and your matlab setup.